# Finding nth occurrence in column - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, find

In VBA: I need to find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th occurrence of "text" in column A. Then, I need to insert the value from a cell from another sheet into the cell to the right of those occurrences. Any ideas?

[This:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR2sa.png)

[Becomes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFC3N.png)

Edit: Put another way, the first value in the column in "Sheet2" must be inserted in the cell the the right of the first occurence of each string in sheet1. The second value in the column must be inserted beside the second occurrence of each string, etc. This could happen up to 7 times.

Comment: Can we expect that "Sheet2" has column headings and has no blank lines between items?  Can we expect that "Sheet1" has column headings, but may have blank lines between items, but all column A items are in ascending order?

Comment: I can make it so that "Sheet2" is formatted as named columns with no blank lines, if that would be better. "Sheet1" won't have column headings (if this is a problem, I can try to figure out a way to format things so that it does). It will have blank rows. Column A items are in ascending order :)

Comment: We just needed to find out data structure outside of the sample that was provided. Presence or absence of Headers can be dealt with.  (Non-ascending A items would have been real hard).  What happens with the Sheet1 unique col A items comes to an end and we have not used up all Sheet2 items?  What happens when we run out of Sheet2 items before we get to the end of Sheet1?

Comment: Please see my edit to the "After" screenshot - the original was not reflective of the result I need. Is it okay now?

Comment: Well, (that changes everything :)  )   that is certainly different.  It is good we are asking these questions, and getting some insight. We still need definition of What happens when we run out of Sheet2 items before we get to the end of Sheet1 --  say when we have 7 values of ABC - D ??  What happens for items 4, 5, 6, 7?? Move nothing? loop back to the top of Sheet2? Go back up and down  Sheet2 in reverse, moving 1,2,3,2,1,2,3?? What might be "obivious" to  you does need to get spelled out.

Comment: Okay! Hopefully this clarifies: in the column of data in "Sheet2", there may be 1 to 7 entries. Taking "ABC - A" as an example:  The instances of "ABC - A" will never exceed the entries in "Sheet2". So if there are 5 entries in "Sheet2", there will never be over 5 instances of "ABC - A". Let me know if I'm omitting anything else!

Comment: Theoretically true.  But the program needs to know what to do when it finds that "wrong" case.  Does it stop with sounding bells and whistles? Does is assume to do nothing and move nothing to items 4,5,6,7 of ABC - D? Silently doing the wrong thing and never telling anybody?  Just because YOU did the data entry and there will never be over x instances, what happens when Herb mis-keys something?  (its midnight, and I need to pause)

Comment: Haha! It would have to just do nothing. If there were more instances of "ABC - A" than entries in "Sheet2", then the remaining "ABC - A"s would have blanks beside them. If there were more entries in "Sheet2" than "ABC - A"s, then the code would have to just add what it could, then move on to the next value in column A :)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be solved with two row indexes  ndx_1 (into Sheet1) and ndx_2 (into Sheet2).

And a few initial values ndx_1_end,  ndx_2_top and ndx_2_end, which are figured out initially.

And memory vars-- prevColA as string that is set to blank initially, and thisColA as string.

```
Loop thru all of Sheet1, 
   get thisColA
   and whenever ColA changes and is non-blank do two things
       Move thisColA value to prevColA
       Reset ndx_2 to its top minus 1
       endif
   then if thisColA is non-blank
       Increment ndx_2 
       If ndx_2 is past its end, 
          then Move spaces to Sheet1.Cells(ndx_1, "B")  'cleanup
          else Move Sheet2.Cell(ndx_2, Col1) to Sheet1.Cells(ndx_1, "B")
       endif
   increment ndx_1
Until end of non-blank Sheet1 ColA items (e.g. ndx_1 >= ndx_1_end)
```

I leave it to you to now write the code to implement this.

Comment: @Jean did this work for you" If so, please click on the check mark.

Comment: Hi, I am so grateful for your response! I am still very new at vba, so I'm currently in the process of trying to understand the code you provided and write it again so that it works for me. :)